Does ADHD conduce to browser "tab hoarding"?
While reading an article about an extreme (and puzzling) case of so-called "tab hoarding" (the tendency to accumulate lots of tabs in one's web browser), I stumbled upon an insightful comment linking the behavior to ADHD:

If you have hundreds or thousands of tabs open... it may be a hint you
have ADHD.

The author goes on to credibly explain how ADHD would contribute to tab hoarding and advise treatment, but is thin on details and provides no evidence.
I found that read provoking enough to open a few tens of tabs more myself, researching the topic, and did find a proper ADHD and Tab Hoarding article by Nicholas Bamonte, which is also interesting and credible, but I don't know who he is, he is publishing on a non-profit website, and he seems to be using mostly amateur sources. I can find studies which link hoarding (in general) with ADHD, but I wonder if "tab hoarding" can be compared to physical hoarding, and neither Google Search nor ChatGPT could help me find research specifically linking tab hoarding with ADHD.
If the English Wikipedia is right about "ADHD represent[ing] the extreme lower end of the continuous dimensional trait (bell curve) of executive functioning and self-regulation", is there EVIDENCE that a person's executive functioning and self-regulation correlates with its tendency to hoard browser tabs?
Or at least, with its tendency towards digital hoarding... if such a thing exists, as Wikipedia suggests? Undoubtedly, this would then be related with another question: Is digital notetaking a variation of hoarding disorder?

Nice question! (Never even occurred to me! )
